# Hadoop - ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop (auth:SIMPLE)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I followed this tutorial http://www.sbarjatiya.com/notes_wiki/index.php/Installing_Hadoop_2.2.0_cluster_on_Ubuntu_12.04_x86_64_Desktops and have successfully installed Hadoop 2.2.0 on a multi-node cluster ( 1 master 2 slaves )

But when i send a MapReduce job to Hadoop with this command

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /in /out
```

I get the following error:

```
    14/05/19 20:14:51 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException                                                as:hadoop (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcNoSuchProtocolException: Unknown               protocol: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB
at  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.getProtocolImpl(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:527)
at  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:566)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)

    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcNoSuchProtocolException: Unknown protocol:   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB
at  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.getProtocolImpl(ProtobufRp cEngine.java:527)
at  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:566)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:104)
at  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getNewApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:170)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getNewApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:135)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate.getNewJobID(ResourceMgrDelegate.java:175)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getNewJobID(YARNRunner.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
    Caused by:  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcNoSuchProtocolException): Unknown protocol: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.getProtocolImpl(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:527)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:566)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1347)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getNewApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:167)
... 32 more
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163657/protobuf-rpc-not-available-on-hadoop-2-2-0-single-node-server